# CUPS test print produces a segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, cups

We have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server running 6.5 that just stopped printing correctly.  When you try to test print from system-config-printer, it segfaults.  I have tried restarting CUPS, but that didn't fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to identify the problem using `lpstat -o` to show the users.

Then run `cancel -u [username]` to cancel their print jobs.

Then restart CUPS.

After that, it quit segfaulting.